# How can I trim the length of a filename in JavaScript but keep the extension?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have some files that are uploaded to my server with huge names, like this:

```
1507633_519504261504361_1763887042_n.jpg
```

In this case, the display length is too long and messes up the format of the page. I'd like it to be trimmed to keep the first few characters (say the first 10) but still keep the .jpg at the end so people know the extension.

```
1507633_519504261504361_1763887042_n.jpg (before)

1507633_51.jpg (after)
```

Is there a relatively straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you split the string by the dot, to split the extension from the filename (assuming you don't have files which contain `.` in their name):

```
var split = initial.split('.');
var filename = split[0];
var extension = split[1];
```

Then, you shorten the length of the filename:

```
if (filename.length > 10) {
    filename = filename.substring(0, 10);
}
```

Last, you concatenate them together.

```
var result = filename + '.' + extension;
```

**Edit**: This is plain Javascript, no jQuery required for this.

Comment: This only works if you are sure that there is no more than one "." in the file name. You should take the length of the array and select the last index instead of just assuming that the extension is on place: 1.

Comment: Have in mind the file name could have multiple dots in it, ensure to take the extension by getting the last item in the array:
    var extension = filename.split('.').pop();

Answer (score 3):

Trim file name, if you have a list of elements with file name and then join extension with trim file name

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.uploadFilesItemHeader').find('#fileName').each(function() {
                    var fileNames = this.innerText;
                    var leftRightStrings = fileNames.split('.');
                    //file name
                    var fName = leftRightStrings[0];
                    //file extension
                    var fExtention = leftRightStrings[1];
                    var lengthFname = fName.length;
                    //if file name without extension contains more than 15 characters   
                    if(lengthFname > 15){
                        $(this).html(fName.substr(0,10) + "..." + fName.substr(-5) + "." +fExtention);
                    }    
        }); 
}); 
    <script>
```

[image: See result in image:]

Answer (score 0):

```
var file_name = file.name;
var arr_filename = file_name.split('.');
var file_ex = arr_filename[ arr_filename.length-1  ];
if ( file_name.length > 14 ) {
   file_name = file_name.substr(0,7) + '...' + file_name.substr(-7);
}
```

There is an error in the responses. the file extension is the last element in the array, because there may be several dots in the file names.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: There is an error in the responses. the file extension is the last element in the array, because there may be several dots in the file names.

Answer (score 0):

**Front-end approach** would be to put three dots in the middle.

```
function getFileName (str) {
  if (str.length > 22) {
    return str.substr(0, 11) + '...' + str.substr(-11)
  }

  return str
}
```

Example usage:

```
getFileName('calm-handsome-man-profile-modern-haircut-178790527.jpeg')

// Output:
// calm-handso...790527.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function that removes the middle of all names 25 chars of length or greater and leaves them otherwise. You could easily adjust the limit here

- This will return the first 15 chars before the extension followed by ... and the 3 chars preceding the extension as well as the extension its self
- This handles cases where filenames have multiple .s in them

```js
  function truncateMiddleOfLongFileNames(fileName) {
    let fileNameLength = fileName.length;

    if (fileNameLength < 25) {
      return fileName;
    } else {
      let extensionDelimiterIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
      let middleRemovedName = `${fileName.substring(0,15)}...${fileName.substring(extensionDelimiterIndex - 3)}`
      return middleRemovedName;
    }
  }
```

It could be used as follows

```js
fileName = 'this_is_too_long_and_i_need_to_fix_it.png';

shortenedFileName = truncateMiddleOfLongFileNames(fileName);
```

to return

```
'this_is_too_lon..._it.png'
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're wanting to accomplish is to rename your files to have a shorter name. This would be a server-side task that jQuery wouldn't be associated with. You could call a server-side script with AJAX that renames, saves and sends back the new filename (which you can then use in jQuery), but this is a pretty bad idea. You're better off renaming the files after they're generated (wherever they're coming from), saving them down, and linking to the new filename directly in your HTML.

Comment: You're right; I was using jQuery a lot lately so I typed that instead of JavaScript. Sorry about that!

Comment: I wasn't referring to jQuery specifically. This is not a JavaScript/jQuery or client-side issue. As the answer below states, you can always substring a file name. But the essential concern is, does that substring actually point to a file that exists, or a path that the server serves an image from?

Comment: I understand; this is the point. The name is being re-written after the filename is pulled from the database simply to look nicer for the user's end, not for the database.

That being said, the code above works fine for the website that I need, with the exception of the point that Kristian Barrett brought up.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're wanting to: 1. Pull an image src from a database, 2. Link to that image via src (eg <img src="myimage123.jpg" />) and 3. Change myimage123.jpg to 123.jpg (or something shorter), but still have the image showing be "myimage123.jpg". This is not possible without some kind of server-side interaction. If you literally change an image element's `src` attribute, the server will think you're actually trying to fetch image `123.jpg` and not `myimage123.jpg`. Thus, your image will break if `123.jpg` doesn't actually exist on your server.

Comment: Like I said, the code above works. I've solved my problem already - thanks, guys!